# Django 1.7 testing, losing data from data migration

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium

I have two test suites

1. Unittests using django.test.TestCase
2. Functional tests using selenium in  django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase

The fixture system was really bad, and with Django 1.7 came the builtin migration tool which recommended data migrations as an alternative. I use a data migration to ensure that some objects will always exist in the database. In this context, think about country codes, state codes, currency names etc.

My UnitTests run just fine, and it wasn't until running my functional tests, that I discovered behaviour similar to what is discussed in 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/wR6hTy9Nu2k .

Imagine something like the following testcase

```
class TestCustomerCreate(CustomerWithInvoicePaymentAndAllocationMixin, FunctionalTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.login_as_superman()

    def test_can_create_customer(self):
        # Do some testing ...

    def test_cannot_create_customer_without_address(self):
        # Do some testing ...
```

When the test suite is run, the database is setup, and all the migrations are installed. The first test, e.g. `test_can_create_customer` commences, `super().setup()` is run to setup the basis of the test, and then the test checks whatever it needs to check. During the first test, my initial data exists, but when the test is done, the database is flushed to prepare for the second test `test_cannot_create_customer_without_address`. So in this second test, I do not have my initial data. No currencies, no country codes, no nothing.

Now, my UnitTests seem to account for this behind the scenes. I have no issues there. But in my FunctionTests, this issue breaks everything, and I cannot make sense of it.

`CustomerWithInvoicePaymentAndAllocationMixin` is just a class the overrides `setUp()` to set the stage for different tests. It is the same class used in both UTs and FTs, so there is no problem there. As far as I can tell, the issue is in the difference between `django.test.TestCase` and `django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase`.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I Made a minimal example to illustrate and explain the issue: https://github.com/eldamir/django_migration_bug/tree/master

Comment: So to clarify, it looks like django.test.TestCase is running your data migration before each test, but StaticLiveServerTestCase only runs it for the first test? Are you absolutely sure? Can you build a minimal repro?

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I made this quick example illustrating the issue: https://github.com/eldamir/django_migration_bug/tree/master

Comment: That looks like a real bug. Open up an issue on the [Django bug tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/)!  The fact that you've got a mimimal repro will really help.   And I'll see if I can find anyone here at pycon.ie to look at it...

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will. You have a good time at pycon :)

Comment: @Eldamir any updates on this? Have you submitted it to the Django bugtracker? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: I did here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23640. As was rejected as the "intended behaviour". I have stopped using data migrations, since they seem broken. Instead i maintain a script that will create the models and have my deployment procedure call that script at the right time